# How can I use for loop / conv instead of filter for my signal

Tags: matlab

I have the following signal.. I wanted to see if I can get the same output using a for loop instead of just using filter to do it. Or is there any other to go about it?

Code:

```
n = 0:1:20;
x = 3*cos(pi*n/3);
y1 = filter(num1,den1,x);
figure()

subplot(2,1,1)
stem(n,y1,'filled','b')
xlabel('n')
title('H1(z)')

y2 = filter(num2,den2,x);
subplot(2,1,2)
stem(n,y2,'filled','k')
xlabel('n')
title('H2(z)')
```

Comment: if you type `help filter`, you will find some hints on how to implement the filter in a simple loop.

Comment: yeah but those are still filter functions, I want to try without using the filter

Comment: without using the Matlab filter function? Thats what I suggest, look at the help of `filter`, and the first equation you see there is what you can implement yourself in a for loop.